# Consulta por mes en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Buen día a la comunidad, mi duda es cómo puedo realizar una consulta a una tabla especifica en base al mes actual, quiero obtener el registro del primer día hasta el último día del mes, sin importar en que día del mes actual nos encontremos, les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**.

Answer (score 3):

Trata con las funciones de **`date_trunc`** y **`extract`**.

Para obtener el primer día del mes actual lo haces con:

```
select extract (day from (select date_trunc('month',current_date)))
```

Para obtener el último día del mes actual lo haces con:

```
select extract (day from (select date_trunc('month',current_date) +'1month' ::interval -'1sec' ::interval))
```

Pienso que podrías guardar esos valores en unas variables y usarlas en tu *query*.